# pass this into function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I want to pass the this instance into.

```
$('.songSelection_input').selectbox().change(function () {
   select_box_check();
});

function select_box_check()
{
   var hashtag = $(this).val();
   var select_id = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

I know I can pass hashtag and select as parameters into the function, but this is just an example. I need to be able to use the "this" within the function.

I plan on reusing the function many times and will be making multiple calls on it, using multiple on changes, which sounds like a terrible idea, why not use just one on change call and just call that instance by using "this", but the plugin I am using is being difficult so I am looking for a quick fix.

So back to my original question, how do I get the $(this) to work within the function?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
$('.songSelection_input').selectbox().change(function () {
   select_box_check.call(this);
});
```

Or

```
$('.songSelection_input').selectbox().change(select_box_check);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.songSelection_input').selectbox().change(function () {
    select_box_check.apply(this);
});
```

Use the function.prototype.apply method to change the context of the method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply